# Fetching object details from NSNotification

Tags: iphone

How can I fetch object from NSNotification object? Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you post you can wrap many objects in an NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary *userInfo=[NSDictionary withObjectsAndKeys:obj1,key1,obj2,key2,nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOTI_NAME" 
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:userInfo];
```

In you observer:

```
-(void)notiObserver:(NSNotification *)notification{

    NSDictionary *userInfo=[notification userInfo];
    OBJ1 *obj1=[userInfo objectForKey:key1];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple. Use the object method of NSNotification.

```
- (void)myMethod:(NSNotification* notification) {
    // Example with a NSArray
    NSArray* myArray = (NSArray*)[notification object];
    // Do stuff
}
```